# mysqli_stmt::fetch(); returns a boolean value but is expected to return an array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a simple Log-in feature, with code that has definitely worked (from a tutorial).
It results in an error notice:

> ***Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in***

Why does `$row = $query->fetch();` return a boolean value and not an array?

Result of the `var_dump($query)` with a correct login data:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { 
    ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) 
    ["insert_id"]=> int(0) 
    ["num_rows"]=> int(0) 
    ["param_count"]=> int(1) 
    ["field_count"]=> int(3) 
    ["errno"]=> int(0) 
    ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["error_list"]=> array(0) { }
    ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" 
    ["id"]=> int(1) 
}
```

Result of the `var_dump($row)`: `bool(true)`

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

        if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? ")) {
            $query->bind_param("s",$email);
            $query->execute();
            var_dump($query);
            $row = $query->fetch();
            var_dump($row);
            if($row) {
                if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                    header("location:https://stackoverflow.com/");
                    exit;
                }
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: I believe that `fetch()` returns false if no records was found/returned. Your dump of the statement seem to confirm that this is the case: `["num_rows"]=> int(0)`

Comment: Magnus' comment in simple language: Enter some data into the database and it will work! ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Also for the editing. There is data in the database though. I don't know why the request returns no result.

Comment: In the database is an index number. I have deleted entries and then added new ones. The index numbers for the new entries did not start at 1 though, after I deleted entries. Could that cause a problem finding the entries?

Comment: I tested it by resetting it, so the index numbers start at 1 again. That doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: You are mixing PDO and mysqli here `$row = $query->fetch();`. Fetch doesn't return any useful value in mysqli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt::fetch()` method does not return an array. It always returns a boolean.

What you are looking for is the `mysqli_result` object. You can get that object by calling `get_result()`. This object has methods like `fetch_assoc()` that will return an array of values. For example:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? ");
$query->bind_param("s", $email);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
if ($row && password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
    header("location:https://stackoverflow.com/");
    exit;
}
```

However, if you wish to select a single field from the database then you can use `mysqli_stmt::fetch()` but you must bind the SQL column to a PHP variable.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ? ");
$query->bind_param("s", $email);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($hashedPassword);
if ($query->fetch() && password_verify($password, $hashedPassword)) {
    header("location:https://stackoverflow.com/");
    exit;
}
```